# AsyncTask когда дисплей выключен

Tags: java, android

Я хочу сделать приложение, которое будет работать когда дисплей телефона будет выключен. Нужно ли использовать asynstask или можно обойтись без него?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Comment: думаю тут не обойтись без Service